# Testing custom hook and getting "Warning: An update to TestHook inside a test was not wrapped in act

Tags: reactjs, unit-testing, react-hooks, react-hooks-testing-library

**EDIT:** I found a solution, coming from [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=PKUDcLGn-80) from Kent C. Dodds.

Just wrap the jest.advanceTimersByTime calls in an act function.

So this:

```js
jest.advanceTimersByTime(510);
```

becomes:

```js
act(()=>jest.advanceTimersByTime(510));
```

---

I've implemented a simple custom hook in order to debounce a value update.

Here is the code:

```js
function useDebounce(value, delay) {
  const [debouncedValue, setDebouncedValue] = useState(value);

  useEffect(() => {
    const handler = setTimeout(() => {
      setDebouncedValue(value);
    }, delay);

    return () => {
      clearTimeout(handler);
    };
  }, [value, delay]);

  return debouncedValue;
}
```

The client of this hook is something like this (very simplified):

```js
function Search(props) {
  const [searchTerm, setSearchTerm] = useState('');
  const debouncedSearchTerm = useDebounce(searchTerm, 500);

  // doing something useful with debouncedSearchTerm....
  // ...
  // ...
}
```

So, I'm trying to test the hook with the code below:

```js
import { renderHook, act } from 'react-hooks-testing-library';
import useDebounce from '../useDebounce';

jest.useFakeTimers();

it.only('should update value after specified delay', () => {
  const { result, rerender } = renderHook(
    ({ value, delay }) => useDebounce(value, delay),
    { initialProps: { value: '', delay: 500 } }
  );

  expect(result.current).toBe('');
  jest.advanceTimersByTime(510);
  expect(result.current).toBe('');

  rerender({ value: 'Hello World', delay: 500 });

  expect(result.current).toBe('');
  jest.advanceTimersByTime(498);
  expect(result.current).toBe('');
  jest.advanceTimersByTime(3);
  expect(result.current).toBe('Hello World');
});
```

Although, the test passes, I get the following warning:

```
console.error node_modules/react-test-renderer/cjs/react-test-renderer.development.js:102

Warning: An update to TestHook inside a test was not wrapped in act(...).        When testing, code that causes React state updates should be wrapped into act(...):        act(() => {      /* fire events that update state */    });    /* assert on the output */        This ensures that you're testing the behavior the user would see in the browser. Learn more at.....       in TestHook        in Suspense
```

I get that if I'm about to call a function in order to update the internal state of the hook (e.g. increment() of a useCounter hook), I have to do it in an *act* function, as the documentation instructs.

But, the useDebounce hook I've implemented changes state by an internal useEffect that runs whenever value or delay change.

How can I get rid of this warning? Is it something wrong with my code? Am I forgetting to add  something in the test code?

Please help!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Jest + react-testing-library: Warning update was not wrapped in act()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55181009/jest-react-testing-library-warning-update-was-not-wrapped-in-act)

Comment: I managed to solve the problem!
Check this: https://github.com/mpeyper/react-hooks-testing-library/issues/97

Answer (score 1):

wrap this line into `act`:

````
it.only('should update value after specified delay', () => {
  const { result, rerender } = renderHook(
    ({ value, delay }) => useDebounce(value, delay),
    { initialProps: { value: '', delay: 500 } }
  );

  expect(result.current).toBe('');
  jest.advanceTimersByTime(510);
  expect(result.current).toBe('');

  rerender({ value: 'Hello World', delay: 500 });

  expect(result.current).toBe('');
  jest.advanceTimersByTime(498);
  expect(result.current).toBe('');
  // once delay time is passed, component is rerendered, so to capture that
  // in unit test, this line should be wrapped in act
  act(() => jest.advanceTimersByTime(3));
  expect(result.current).toBe('Hello World');
});```
````