# MUI Select causing act() console error using fireEvent

Tags: testing, jestjs, material-ui

Unit testing a select component:

```
<FormControl fullWidth>
  <InputLabel id="demo-simple-select-label">
    {t("StrategyManager.Select_Action_Origin")}
  </InputLabel>
  <Select
    name="actionOrigin"
    label="Select Action Origin"
    id="operator-select"
    value={formik.values.actionOrigin}
    onChange={(event) => handleFormDataChange(event)}
    fullWidth
    inputProps={{
      id: "actionOrigin",
      "data-testid": "actionOrigin",
    }}
  >
    <MenuItem value={strategyActions.communications.value}>
      {t(strategyActions.communications.label)}
    </MenuItem>
    <MenuItem value={strategyActions.timer.value}>
      {t(strategyActions.timer.label)}
    </MenuItem>
    <MenuItem value={strategyActions.socials.value}>
      {t(strategyActions.socials.label)}
    </MenuItem>
  </Select>
</FormControl>;
```

I seem to only be able to change the value in a unit test using `fireEvent.change(actionOriginSelect, { target: { value: strategyActions.timer.value } });` I'd prefer to use the `user.selectOptions(actionOriginSelect, strategyActions.timer.value)` but this for some reason doesn't update the value of the targeted input so I'm left with the first implementation.

The test is passing however it is causing a console error stating that an update was not wrapped in act(...)
[image]

The full test is here:

```
it("selects the timer option and reveals the action selector without showing a popup", async () => {
  const user = userEvent.setup();
  render(
    <ActionsDrawer/>,
  );

  const actionOriginSelect = screen.getByTestId("actionOrigin");
  expect(actionOriginSelect).toBeInTheDocument();

  // selects value and inputs it in the field but causes console error in process?
  fireEvent.change(actionOriginSelect, {
    target: { value: strategyActions.timer.value },
  });

  // ideally would prefer to use the below line of code but for some reason actionOriginSelect won't change value
  // await user.selectOptions(actionOriginSelect, strategyActions.timer.value);

  const actionTypeSelect = screen.getByTestId("actionType");
  expect(actionTypeSelect).toBeInTheDocument();

  // Ensure no confirmation modal is displayed
  const changeOriginModal = screen.queryByText(
    "StrategyManager.Confirm_Change_Origin",
  );
  expect(changeOriginModal).toBeNull();
});
```

I've tried the following:

- wrapping different parts of the above test in act() in the hopes of finding which part needed to be wrapped
- Tried awaiting the fire event that I assume is causing the errortried
- Tried implementing waitfor on the assertions after the fireEvent
- Tried jest timers as suggested by articles on the above act warning

None seem to remove or clear the console warning from the terminal.

Any help or suggestions on how to improve the test or implement user.selectOptions would be really appreciated. Alternatively failing that, help as to what part of the above needs to be wrapped in act to remove the console errors would be beneficial as I'm happy with the test if this is the best I can get but obviously multiple tests causing this console warning isn't very good and I'd like to understand this issue better to avoid it in future.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally found the answer after a few days of trial and error I came across this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55181009/jest-react-testing-library-warning-update-was-not-wrapped-in-act?rq=2) which fixed the error I was getting. I had to add await act(async () => {}) around the fire event and add an await

```
await act(async () => {
fireEvent.change(await actionOriginSelect, {target: {value: strategyActions.timer.value}};
```